# How to play short notifications and continue playing - without audioClip

Tags: sonos

I want to play short audio clips to notify of events. Basically exactly what the [audioClip API](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/audioclip/audioclip/) does, but audioClip is only available to a very limited set of players. Especially the Play:1 is not supported, and I'd really like to support it with my service.

I figure it's possible to play this notification using [loadStreamUrl](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/playbacksession/loadstreamurl/).
However, when the player (or group) is currently playing something, I want to resume that after the notification was finished.

While there is a [getPlaybackStatus](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/playback/getplaybackstatus/) function that I can use to receive all information about what is currently playing before sending the notification, I'm having a hard time figuring out how I can - under all circumstances (a stream is loaded, line in is selected, local music is played, etc.) - restore the previous state exactly as it was before. It seems ridiculously complex to me, and I can't even reliably test all circumstances as I don't own players with Line In, for example.

Is there some easier way that I am missing, or has anyone done that before and can point to a well-tested implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible with the Control API. The most obvious example of why is in the case of a partner app (like Pandora or Tidal) playing straight to Sonos speakers. If you start playback via a stream, you will end the partners' playback session on the speaker, and there's no way to get it back.

Attempting to massage playback of content like this will result in a very poor experience for listeners.

Comment: Thanks for (quick!) the answer, Matt. It's a pity that it's impossible to mimick audioClip on older players. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Resuming prior content is actually pretty impossible even with the LAN api. It is a pain that audioClip is only available on the newer hardware devices, not really sure why, and can only hope the supported list keeps expanding.